# How to write the einsum operation: 'i,jk->ijk' in tensorial product form?

Tags: math, pytorch, tensor

I am using pytorch and want to broadcast a vector from 1D (features) to a 3D tensor (features×height×width) to condition the encoding of an image with a Convolutional Neural Network. As is done in Figure S1 of this [Deepmind paper](https://storage.googleapis.com/deepmind-media/papers/Neural_Scene_Representation_and_Rendering_preprint.pdf).
For now I am using this:

```
# features: 1D vector
f = torch.einsum('i,jk->ijk',features,torch.ones([5,5]))
```

Comment: What's wrong with just using the einsum?

Comment: Not exactly sure why `numpy` is here . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using broadcast semantics you could alternatively compute this using

```py
f = features.reshape(-1, 1, 1) * torch.ones(1, 5, 5)
```